# Application crashes while loading image (java.lang.OutOfMemoryError)

Tags: android, android-activity, imageview, out-of-memory, android-gallery

I have two activities. In start activity there are small images. Click by each of them and then open the other activity with the Gallery at `ViewPager`.

When open the Gallery it slide images perfectly without any problems.

But when I go back to the start activity and reopen the Gallery, app crashed with
`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError` bitmap size exceeds vm budget

I tried to re-size images, get it smaller, but it does not help. It also crashed but a little bit later.

I think when the activity with Gallery and all images hasn't been destroyed. It has memory leak.

For Gallery I use `AndroidTouchGallery`: [link](https://github.com/Dreddik/AndroidTouchGallery)

This is the example app with this code: workspace [link on GoogleDrive](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9s5zjOLJ6pbRGlIaTUtZHIwckE/edit?usp=sharing)

My code.
Start Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ArrayList<String> list_big_images = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_big_images.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/small/evropeyska_misiya1_s.jpg");
        list_big_images.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/small/evropeyska_misiya2_s.jpg");
        list_big_images.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/small/evropeyska_misiya3_s.jpg");

        ArrayList<String> list_big_images_big = new ArrayList<String>();
        list_big_images_big.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/big/evropeyska_misiya1_b.jpg");
        list_big_images_big.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/big/evropeyska_misiya2_b.jpg");
        list_big_images_big.add("http://www.oa.edu.ua/assets/images/n/2013/big/evropeyska_misiya3_b.jpg");      


         //get Screen size
        int width; //Display width
        int height; //Display height

        if (  Integer.valueOf(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) > 13 ) {
               Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
                  Point size = new Point();
                  display.getSize(size);
                  width = size.x;
                  height = size.y;
        } else {
             Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
             width = display.getWidth();
             height = display.getHeight();
        }

        ImageView[] imageViewArray = new ImageView[list_big_images.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i<list_big_images.size(); i++)  
             try {
                    String url = list_big_images.get(i);
                    //url_img_small.add(text);
                    // Let's create the missing ImageView
                    imageViewArray[i] = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);                               

                    // Now the layout parameters, these are a little tricky at first
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width/3, width/3);
                    imageViewArray[i].setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
                    imageViewArray[i].setId(i + 1); // BELOW id 0 doesn't work
                    imageViewArray[i].setPadding(0, 5, 5, 0);
                    if (i > 0) {
                        if (i % 3 == 0){
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageViewArray[i - 3].getId());
                        }
                        else {
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, imageViewArray[i - 1].getId());
                            if (i>2)
                                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, imageViewArray[i - 3].getId());
                        };
                    }

                    Drawable drawable = grabImageFromUrl(url);
                    imageViewArray[i].setImageDrawable(drawable);

                    final ArrayList<String> list_big_images_big2 = list_big_images_big;
                    final int pos = i;
                    imageViewArray[i].setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener()

                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                System.out.println(v.getId());
                                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), Full_Image_Activity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("ArrayImgBig", list_big_images_big2);
                                intent.putExtra("pos", pos+1);
                                startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

                            }
                        });

                    // Let's get the root layout and add our ImageView
                    RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.moreImages);
                    layout.addView(imageViewArray[i], params);
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   
        }

    //load Image from Url
    private Drawable grabImageFromUrl(String url) throws Exception {
        return Drawable.createFromStream(
                (InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), "src");
    }


}
```

It`s Activity with Gallery

```
public class Full_Image_Activity extends Activity {

    ArrayList <String> ArrayImgBig = null;
    int id_news;
    private GalleryViewPager mViewPager;
    int pos ; //Picture Position
    UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_full__image);

        ArrayImgBig = getIntent().getExtras().getStringArrayList("ArrayImgBig");
        pos = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("pos");

        UrlPagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new UrlPagerAdapter(Full_Image_Activity.this, ArrayImgBig);
        pagerAdapter.setOnItemChangeListener(new OnItemChangeListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemChange(int currentPosition)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Full_Image_Activity.this, "Current item is " + currentPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        });

        mViewPager = (GalleryViewPager)findViewById(R.id.viewer);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(pos);  
    }


    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        pagerAdapter = null;
        mViewPager = null;
        System.gc();
    }
}
```

I use the method `onDestoy`. But it does not help. Everything is the same.

The log:

```
11-27 15:39:59.239: I/System.out(471): 1
11-27 15:40:00.248: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 1638K, 48% free 4736K/9031K, external 15372K/16229K, paused 116ms
11-27 15:40:00.879: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 35K, 48% free 4742K/9031K, external 17773K/18518K, paused 100ms
11-27 15:40:02.519: I/dalvikvm(471): Jit: resizing JitTable from 2048 to 4096
11-27 15:40:04.959: W/KeyCharacterMap(471): No keyboard for id 0
11-27 15:40:04.959: W/KeyCharacterMap(471): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
11-27 15:40:05.159: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXPLICIT freed 155K, 49% free 4654K/9031K, external 20410K/21124K, paused 111ms
11-27 15:40:05.738: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXPLICIT freed 3K, 49% free 4652K/9031K, external 20410K/21124K, paused 223ms
11-27 15:40:10.703: I/System.out(471): 2
11-27 15:40:11.748: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 43K, 48% free 4754K/9031K, external 20410K/21124K, paused 106ms
11-27 15:40:11.998: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 4K, 48% free 4780K/9031K, external 23046K/23760K, paused 112ms
11-27 15:40:12.048: E/dalvikvm-heap(471): 1334000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
11-27 15:40:12.208: E/GraphicsJNI(471): VM won't let us allocate 1334000 bytes
11-27 15:40:12.208: D/dalvikvm(471): GC_FOR_MALLOC freed 0K, 48% free 4780K/9031K, external 23046K/23760K, paused 87ms
11-27 15:40:12.229: D/skia(471): --- decoder->decode returned false
11-27 15:40:12.238: W/dalvikvm(471): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:525)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:102)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at ru.truba.touchgallery.TouchView.UrlTouchImageView$ImageLoadTask.doInBackground(UrlTouchImageView.java:1)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-27 15:40:12.248: E/AndroidRuntime(471):  ... 4 more
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object)

Answer (score 0):

edit your onDestroy to the following:

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    pagerAdapter = null;
    mViewPager = null;
    System.gc();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

or put the code into the onPause()

Comment: try to edit onDrestroy and try to use onPause(). But i have the same error. Update Question. Add error log.

Answer (score 0):

You could check that in your viewpager adapter you are overriding destroyItem. This will remove the view when it is no longer visible on screen, thus freeing up memory allocated for that image.

example:

```
    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }
```

I'd also recommend you use an imageloader like [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) or universal image loader to load images asynchronously off the ui thread, and have their allocation in memory handled for you so you don't get out of memory exceptions...